# test a string against each element of an array

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash shell scripting and it is my first day and first time to post a question here in stackoverflow. I already searched the archive to no avail. I hope someone can help me.

I have an array like this

```
declare -a SID=("mydb1" "mydb2" "mydb3")
```

In my script, the user will be prompted to enter a string and it will be stored in `$DBNAME` variable.

For example a user entered "mydb2" (without quote), this will be stored in `$DBNAME` variable.

I want to create a loop and I want the input of the user to be tested against each element of the `${SID[@]`} variable.

And when a match found, it will exit from the loop and continue with the next command in a script.

Please help me create a script to match a string value against each element of an array variable.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to happen when a match is found? Are you only testing THAT a match is found?  Or do you care which match?

Comment: Hi Mark thank you for your concern. Yes I wanted to test the input of the user and it should be matched with one of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is check that the user entered a valid dbname, do this:

```
declare -a SID=("mydb1" "mydb2" "mydb3")
case " ${SID[*]} " in
    *\ $DBNAME\ *)
        echo Entered a correct DB name! Good job, pal!
        ;;
    *)
        echo Try again
        ;;
 esac
```

This can lead to false-positives in cases where you allow space-containing user-input.  If this is a concern, you can solve the problem by using a non-space delimiter that is not allowed in the user's input. For example:

```
case ".mydb1.mydb2.mydb3." in
    *.$DBNAME.*)
```

If your user input is completely open-ended, and unvalidated, then a for loop is probably your best bet, as explained in @glennjackson's answer.

Comment: I really appreciate that. Thank you! 

How about if the array values are not explicitly declared in the loop. Something like this, but this one is not working.

read -p "Enter DB name :" DBNAME

for DB in "${SID[@]}"
do
   if [[ DB != DBNAME ]] ; then
      printf "Match not found\n"
   else
      printf "Match found\n"
   fi
done

Comment: You could use a for loop as you suggest, but that's messier if all you care about is finding a match, because you have to keep a temporary variable that you set to true when you find a match, then check that variable after the loop to see if a match was found.

Comment: Flimzy and Mark thank you very much. It worked! People like you motivates newbies like me to pursue our goal to learn more. I really appreciate it. In the meantime, I will browse the archive and try to immerse myself with the system. :)

Comment: Sure! Tell me how to up-vote and accept your answer. I already clicked the YES button, is that it?

Comment: Sorry not enough reputation. Will do next time that's for sure. Thanks again!

Comment: *@Flimzy:* The code can accept an invalid value, eg. if the user enters `"mydb1 mydb2"` ... PS. typo: ${SID[*}}

Comment: @fered: Good catch.  I've updated my answer to acknowledge the possible weakness, with a possible work-around that may work in many cases.

Answer (score 5):

@Flimzy's approach is good. The correct way to use a for-loop is

```
for db in "${SID[@]}"; do
  if [[ $db = $DBNAME ]]; then
    echo yes
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: +1, because this answer works as intended...  On the other hand, I'll mention Flimzy's answer here (because my comment to his queston is buried at the end of a long list of comments).. Flimsy's answer can give false positives, eg. "mydb1 mydb2"

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to check that $DBNAME is an entry is $SID, the easiest thing to do is probably:

```
if echo ${SID[@]} | grep -wq "$DBNAME"; then
   # DBNAME is in SID array
fi
```

Note that -w and -q are non-standard options to grep, so you might want:

```
if echo ${SID[@]} | grep "\<$DBNAME\>" > /dev/null; then
   # DBNAME is in SID array
fi
```

This will fail if any of the entries in SID contain spaces, and
other odd characters will undoubtedly cause problems as well.

Comment: This can return a false positive, even if entries in SID contain no spaces, eg. if the user enters "mydb1 mydb2"

Comment: Follow up to this issue. I did further research and I believe it should be:

if echo ${SID[@]} | grep -o "$DBNAME"; then
  echo "Match found"
fi

Not sure really.  :-)

The grep -wq "$DBNAME" and grep "\<$DBNAME\>"  did not work for me.

Again thanks for all the contributions!